# Is there a simple, modern, way to type hint physical units in Python 3.9+?

Tags: python, mypy

I am faced with a problem where I have to create a lot of classes with a lot of attributes that relate to physical quantities. I use `dataclass` to make this easy. However, these attributes can relate to different physical units, and I would like to add these units as type hints. I have tried using `Annotated`, `NewType` and `TypeVar`, but none of these solutions passes mypy:

#### units.py

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Annotated, NewType, TypeVar

meter = TypeVar('meter', bound=float)
um = Annotated[float, 'um']
ohm = NewType('ohm', float)


@dataclass
class Data:
    length_1: meter = 10e-3
    length_2: um = 20
    R: ohm = 50
```

#### `> mypy units.py`:

```
units.py:11: error: Type variable "units.meter" is unbound  [valid-type]
units.py:11: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[meter]" or "Protocol[meter]" base class to bind "meter" inside a class)
units.py:11: note: (Hint: Use "meter" in function signature to bind "meter" inside a function)
units.py:12: error: Variable "units.um" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
units.py:12: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
units.py:13: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "ohm")  [assignment]
```

I understand that I misuse the typing module slightly in all cases here, but is there any way to achieve anything like this that passes mypy? I would like to pass a `float` to the dataclass `__init__` and not another special type, and then build some conversion to SI-units in the `__post_init__` of the dataclass using the type types specified in the class definition, or something similar. The reason is mainly to minimize code redundancy, since I will have to write a lot of generic classes, and I want the readability to be high.

Comment: If the conversion between different units is not involved, `NewType` is appropriate. At this time, `R: ohm = ohm(50)` should be used instead of `R: ohm = 50`.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would declare a new type that inherits from the built-in type you want to use to represent it. e.g.

```
class Meter(float):
    ...
```

You can then use this in your data class as follows:

```
@dataclass
class Data:
    length_1: Meter = Meter(10e-3)
```

Comment: How do you initialise/assign to `length_1`? Can you use a `float` and not get an error from mypy?

Comment: Good spot Peter, if the typing is strict then you need to assign a Meter value which can be done using `Meter(10e-3)` instead of `10e-3`. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Then might as well just do `l = Meter(1.0)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this results in two of the things I am trying to avoid: I have to pass a `Meter` object both as a default and every time I instantiate a `Data`-object, otherwise mypy will complain.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest to you then... I'm not sure if it makes sense to have a strict typing suggestion for Meter but then want to enter in a float and not have mypy complain.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, there is not a standard, native support for physical units in Python. However, there is a plethora of modules that can manage unit/value pairs. Here is a [small overview](https://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/python-units-quantities-packages).

I was first using [Pint](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint). Even though this module is very mature and offers a lot of functionality, I personally disliked its use of registries and very verbose notation of units. I personally recommend "[Physical Units](https://vrtulka23.github.io/scinumtools/units/index.html)" module from "[scinumtools](https://github.com/vrtulka23/scinumtools)" package that I am working on. Below is a small example how to use it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scinumtools.units import Quantity, Unit
>>> Quantity(23.34, 'kg*m2/s2').to('erg')     # unit conversions
Quantity(2.334e+08 erg)
>>> u = Unit()                                # calculations with units 
>>> 34*u.cm + 53*u.dm  
Quantity(5.640e+02 cm)
>>> Quantity(23.34, 'cm', abse=0.03)          # uncertainities
Quantity(2.3340(30)e+01 cm)
>>> Quantity(3, 'A').value('dBA')             # logarithmic units
9.542425094393248
>>> np.sqrt(Quantity([23,59,20,10], 'm2'))    # arrays and NumPy
Quantity([4.796 7.681 4.472 3.162] m)
```